# how to segment a binary image to get bounding boxes

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, object-detection, image-segmentation

my input image：
[image]

I want get bounding box for each object：
[image]

the input image is a binary image which segmented with cnn（salient object detection，but the black areas sticked to each other，I want to seperate them to get the bounding box for each box。
the original image：
[image]

with salient object detection and post-processing we get：
[image]

but I want this：
[image]

ps:I don't want approaches like yolo/SSD which need to train with custom dataset

Comment: you need an object detector, not a semantic segmentation. discard your approach. you create your own problems by insisting on working with that mask. it contains no information about object boundaries. -- welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre].

Answer (score 0):

If you know all input objects are round, I would probably compute edges first, then use this as input to Hough transform algorithm. Search for 'coin detection from images' which is very similar to your problem.